# Place LinearLayout at bottom of another LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to place LinearLayout containing gridview at the bottom. Please suggest what can be done.

Below is my XML code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parentRelativeView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/darkgreen"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEquation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/darkorange"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2+2=?"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtOutput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/darkpurple"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
        android:id="@+id/donut_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtOutput"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        custom:donut_finished_color="#30b8f2"
        custom:donut_progress="01"
        custom:donut_text_size="50dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/numberGridView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0.4dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:horizontalSpacing="0.4dp"
            android:numColumns="@integer/grid_rows"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="0.4dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why place the GridView inside another LinearLayout, it makes the inner LinearLayout redundant if it only has a single child

Comment: I want to add border to gridview, for this I want to have background of LinearLayout.

Comment: As far as I can see it is at the bottom. Could you be more specific please. Also, you could try to use the Design tab to play around and see how you like it, you might find it a bit easier.

Comment: It is at the bottom among all the controls but I want the linearlayout to be at the bottom of the screen. I tried using the design tab but with no help.

Comment: To do this you should use RelativeLayout

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can align some items to top and others to bottom in `LinearLayout`. We have `RelativeLayout` for purposes like this. With `RelativeLayout` you can align anything to anything so I recommend you to use it.